# How to remove certain characters

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to remove single vowels from a string, but not if a vowel is double same.

For example string

> "I am keeping a foobar"

should print out as

> "m keepng foobr"

I have tried everything but didn't come up with a solution so far.

Comment: Shouldn't it print "m keepng foobr"?

Comment: And what about triple vowels? Do you keep all three, or do you remove one?

Comment: You should try to write code instead of "everything" and post it in your question. Trying "everything" rarely helps - you usually need to target your attempts. :)

Comment: What if it's "fooobar"?

Comment: Clearly you haven't tried everything, as that set would include your required answer. What we can't tell is whether you've tried *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this logic:

1. loop trough string and check two by two characters
2. if (isBothVowelsAndEqual()) do nothing; else removeFirstChar();

EDIT:

```
public List<char> vowels = "AEIOUaeiou".ToList();
public bool isBothVowelsAndEqual(char first, char second)
    {
       return (first == second && vowels.Contains(first));
    }

const string s = "I am keeeping a foobar";
string output=String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (isBothVowelsAndEqual(s[i], s[i + 1]))
    {                        
       output = output + s[i] + s[i+1];
       i++;
    }
    else
    {
       if (!vowels.Contains(s[i])) {
       output += s[i];
    }
  }                
}
Console.WriteLine(output.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"([aeiou])\1", "");
```

Though for `I am keeping a foobar`, it will give you `m keepng  foobr`, which is different to your required `m keepng foobr`, as you're stripped spaces out of your required result, too.

If you want to remove the extraneous spaces, then it's a three step operation: remove vowels; remove proceeding/trailing spaces; remove double spaces.

```
var raw = Regex.Replace(input, @"([aeiou])\1", "");
var trimmed = raw.Trim();
var final = trimmed.Replace("  ", " ");
```